# Flet SearchBar's on_change is not working, even in the flet's offical example

Tags: flet

I'm building a app with flet and i want a dropdown searchbox on which according to the letters i'm typing in the bar the dropdown list need to filter. For this i need to get a value from the searchbar on event on_change, But on_change is not working in the ft.SearchBar. Pls suggest the way to make it working.

Pls suggest the solution for this problem. Thanks in advance